# Firebase Firestore: orderBy combined with where causes error "Operation was rejected"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking at the Firebase Cloud Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) for orderBy. When I try to execute this

```
var facultyQuery = facultyRef.where("department", "==", "Core Teacher").orderBy('bb_last_name', 'desc');
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation`s execution. (firestore/failed-precondition).
```

Both of these simpler cases work just fine:

```
var facultyQuery = facultyRef.orderBy('bb_last_name', 'asc');
var facultyQuery = facultyRef.where("department", "==", "Core Teacher");
```

But when I combine the where and the orderBy, something I have done before with other Firestore collections, it fails.

Here is a sample record:
[image]

Comment: Did you create the necessary index on `department` and `bb_last_name`? You should get a better error message than this if you forgot, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: I did not. The documentation states that "...queries that only use equality clauses don't need additional indexes" so I did not think I needed one. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: It's the additional `orderBy` that makes me think it might. But it would usually give a very clear message about that.

Answer (score 7):

Tip for anyone that needs it,

If you've forgotten to create an index and are getting the above error, run `adb logcat` and then attempt to load the data again - it usually gives you a URL link which will very kindly create the required index for you.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue, and Frank van Puffelen's comment fixed it for me. You need to create a composite index for "department" and "bb_last_name". Since "department" uses the equality operator, it doesn't matter whether it is ascending or descending in your index.

Comment: Searched all over and didn't find this. I also had to match the ascending/descending on the index to match my query (which makes sense). Thank you.