# Getting error: Ensure your query has been indexed via the Firebase console. on querying from subcollection?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is the error:
[image]

This is the query I'm making:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    firestore()
      .collectionGroup('Members')
      .where('uid', '==', `${uid}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id);
      });
  }
```

I tried to find possible solutions and for this and I found that on running `adb logcat` or `react-native log-android`, the error is presented with a link to create indices for the query. I ran both and didn't get any link.

On running `adb logcat`:
[image]

On running `react-native log-android`:
[image]

Please guide me to solve this issue.

EDIT: 
I have also created a composite index in my console but I am still getting the same error.
[image]

Comment: You will definitely need an [index for the collectionGroup query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/47745241/3399890 which involves an orderBy but it is the same problem.

Comment: I went over the docs and created an index manually in the firebase console, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a single field collection group query, which we do not build indexes for by default. Note this is a single field index, not a composite field index.

In the console, go to indexes, then single field indexes. Add an exemption:

- Collection Id = `Members`
- field = `uid`.

Make sure you check the 'Collection Group' scope then click next:

- Turn on 1 or more of 'Ascending' and 'Descending' (either works in this case)
- Click Save

Comment: This worked for me but I still didn't understand why is mine a single field collection group query? Can you please elaborate ? I'm new at this.
For e.g if I had used ```collectionGroup('Members').where().orderBy()``` then would it become composite ??